# Defects filtered to Initative

Tags: rally

looking for help on filtering Defects to initiatives.

I can filter User Stories to Initiative by using the following filter:

```
var myFilters = [
            {
            property: 'Feature.Parent.Parent',
            operation: '=',
            value: selectedInitRef //Initiative Value from Drop Down
            },
                        ];
```

But I cannot seem to get down a level to Defects, below is the hierarchy i use in my subscription.

Initiative
    Theme
        Feature
            User Story
                Defect

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible with a recent update to WSAPI.  In v2.0 the Requirement field on Defect is now of type HierarchicalRequirement.  The following filter should now work:

```
var myFilters = [{
    property: 'Requirement.Feature.Parent.Parent',
    operation: '=',
    value: selectedInitRef //Initiative Value from Drop Down
}];
```

Comment: as it turns out i had some extra time to play around with this today and i think i have a fix.  i'll post back here when it gets shipped early next week.

Comment: This was deployed to production this afternoon.  Let me know how it goes!